# jQuery Tabs - Load contents only when clicked

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, tabs

I am relatively new to jQuery and web development.

I am using jQuery UI Tabs to create tabs.

But I want the contents to be loaded only when I select a particular tab.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, I assume when the user clicks a tab, you intend to fetch content dynamically, via AJAX. This really involves two things, **setting an onclick even for your tab** and **fetching the data via ajax**.

**Setting an onclick event**

Give your tab an class, for example *my_tab*. Let's say that when the user clicks the tab you want the *handle_tab_click()* function to fire. Here's an example of binding the *onclick* event to your *my_tab* tab:

```
$(".my_tab").bind("click", handle_tab_click);
```

Your *handle_tab_click()* function will be given an *event* argument which will be able to provide you with information on the element that fired the event (in this case, the element with class name *my_tab*).

```
function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("my_tab")) { /* handle tab click */ }
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("my_tab_2")) { /* a different tab click */ }
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("my_tab_3")) { /* ... */ }
}
```

See the JQuery *event* documentation for more details [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn).

**Fetching the data via ajax**

Fetching data will require you to invoke a remote script while supplying information about which tab was clicked (in order to fetch the appropriate information). In the following snippet, we're invoking the remote script *myscript.php*, supplying the HTTP GET argument *tab_clicked=my_tab* and calling the function *tab_fetch_cb* when the script returns.  The final parameter is the type of data being returned (it's up to you to choose).

```
$.get("myscript.php", {tab_clicked, "my_tab"}, tab_fetch_cb, "text/json/xml")
```

It's up to you to design *myscript.php* to handle the *tab_clicked* parameter, fetch the appropriate data and return it (i.e. write it back out to the client).

Here's an example for *tab_fetch_cb*:

```
function tab_fetch_cb(data, status) {
    // populate your newly opened tab with information 
    // returned from myscript.php here
}
```

You can read more about the JQuery *get* function [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype), and JQuery ajax functions [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

I'm sorry I can't be more specific in my examples, but a lot of the processing is really dependant on your task.  As it looks as it has already been pointed out, you may look to some JQuery plugins for a canned solution to your problem.  That being said, it never hurts to learn how to do this stuff manually w/ JQuery.

Good luck.

Comment: It's easier to use jQuery UI's Tab plugin. See CMS' comment below.

Answer (score 14):

UI/Tabs support loading tab content on demand via Ajax, check [this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Ajax_mode) example.

Comment: The link is no more valid, please update it.

Answer (score 1):

Loading content via Ajax adds the complexity of dealing with bookmarking / browser back buttons. Depending on your situation, you should consider loading new content with a full page request. Handling the bookmarking/browser back involves using adding anchor info in the URL.

Also, check out [LavaLamp](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/?p=7) for tab selection. It's pretty nifty looking.

Comment: That link to 'lavalamp' gives a dangerous message in my virusscanner.

Answer (score 1):

By default a tab widget will swap between tabbed sections onClick, but the events can be changed to onHover through an option. Tab content can be loaded via Ajax by setting an href on a tab.

source: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Comment: The link is no more valid, please update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, you can try this gem [bettertabs](https://github.com/agoragames/bettertabs)

It supports ajax tabs.