# I want my tabs to be loaded dynamically (only when clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Tabs- Load Contents only when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502391/jquery-tabs-load-contents-only-when-clicked)

Hi,

I am relatively new to jquery and web development.
I am using jquery tabs to create tabs.
here is the code

`<div id="tabs-1">
            <%@ include file="page1.jsp"%>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <%@ include file="Page2.jsp"%>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <%@ include file="Page3.jsp"%>
        </div>
</div>`

and javascript is

each and every page is loading before clicking the tab but i want them to load dynamically

So can you please help me get out of this mess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the Jquery ui options,

it has the ability to load content via ajax (i believe you simply put a url in the href instead of just #

and it will load the content from the url

Comment: @Hailwood..Simple but Superb..Great thought..